# In an integer program, how I can force a binary variable to equal 1 if some condition holds?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, constraint, integer-programming, logical-constraints

Suppose we have a binary or continuous variable $x$, a binary variable $y$, and a constant $b$, and we want to enforce a relationship like

> If $x \gtreqless b$, then $y = 1$.

How can we write this using one or more linear constraints?

Comment: I have answered a bunch of questions like this one on math.SE and SO. In the spirit of [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I'm doing some self-Q&A here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**If $x$ is binary:** Then the "if" condition really means either "$x = 0$" or "$x=1$".

*To enforce "if $x=0$ then $y=1$"*: use
$$y \ge 1-x.$$
*To enforce "if $x=1$ then $y=1$"*: use
$$y \ge x.$$

If you want to require that $y=1$ *if and only if* the condition holds, then replace the $\ge$s above with $=$s.

**If $x$ is continuous:** In this case, numerical inaccuracy might produce errors, so be prepared for $y$ to be set incorrectly if $x$ is *close to* but on the “wrong” side of $b$. To avoid this, you can increase or decrease $b$ a little bit to provide some buffer.

*To enforce "if $x < b$ then $y=1$"*: 
$$b - x \le My,$$
where $M$ is a large constant. The logic is that if $b - x > 0$, then $y$ must equal 1, and otherwise it may equal 0.

*To enforce "if $x > b$ then $y=1$"*:
$$x - b \le My,$$
with similar logic as above.

*To enforce "if $x = b$ then $y=1$"*: This one is tricky. I'm not sure my approach is the easiest. (Anyone have a better solution?) We really can't check for $x=b$, but we can check for $b-\delta \le x \le b+\delta$ for some small $\delta > 0$. To do this, we introduce two new binary decision variables.

Let $z_1$ be a binary variable that equals 1 if $x > b - \delta$, equals 0 if $x < b - \delta$, and could equal either if $x = b - \delta$. 
Enforce this definition by adding the following constraints:
\begin{alignat}{2}
Mz_1 & \ge x - b + \delta\tag1 \\
M(1-z_1) & \ge b - x - \delta\tag2 
\end{alignat}
The logic is:

- If $x > b - \delta$, then (1) forces $z_1=1$ and (2) has no effect.
- If $x < b - \delta$, then (2) forces $z_1=0$ and (1) has no effect.
- If $x = b - \delta$, then (1) and (2) have no effect; $z_1$ could equal either 0 or 1.

Next, introduce a second binary variable $z_2$, which equals 1 if $x < b + \delta$, equals 0 if $x > b + \delta$, and could equal either if $x = b + \delta$. Introduce the following constraints:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
Mz_2 & \ge b - x + \delta\tag3 \\
M(1-z_2) & \ge x - b - \delta\tag4
\end{alignat}$$
The logic is similar:

- If $x < b + \delta$, then (3) forces $z_2=1$ and (4) has no effect.
- If $x > b + \delta$, then (4) forces $z_2=0$ and (3) has no effect.
- If $x = b + \delta$, then (3) and (4) have no effect; $z_2$ could equal either 0 or 1.

From constraints (1)-(4), we can say that if $z_1=z_2=1$, then $b - \delta \le x \le b + \delta$. Therefore, we can enforce "if $b - \delta \le x \le b + \delta$ then $y=1$" using:
$$y \ge z_1 + z_2 - 1.$$

*Note*: If your model is relatively large, i.e., it takes a non-negligible amount of time to solve, then you need to be careful with big-$M$-type formulations. In particular, you want $M$ to be as small as possible while still enforcing the logic of the constraints above.

Comment: In the first part where $x$ is binary, what if I have 2 or more binary variable that leads to the decision of $y$ like $x$ and $z$ when $x=1 \wedge z = 1$ then $y = 1$

Comment: Then you'd have to formulate separate constraints in which you enforce the definition of $y$ and then use $y$ as described above.

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: Lets say I have 4 binary variable $a,b,c,d$ if all $a,b,c,d = 1$ the $x = 1$ else $x =0$, then can I write $x \ge 3 - a+b+c+d$

Comment: @LarrySnyder610: how small could we set $\delta$ to?

Comment: I'm brushing up on ILPs and learning about "big-M" type formulations. Is it correct that this formulation fails if `abs(x - b) > M`? Is there any way to formulate the logical constraint such that it holds in general, or is that not possible? (I'm guessing not possible because a non-zero sloped line always diverges to +-infinity?)

Comment: Yeah, I think you need M to be large enough that |x - b| < M

Answer (score 12):

Rather than linearising the logical constraint, I would try the logical constraints built in a solver. Gurobi and SCIP both have indicator constraints.

My colleague works with these a lot and he’s finding the indicator constraints in Gurobi perform worse than big-M. He’s in contact with the Gurobi developers so I might be able to get more info if there’s interest.

Comment: I've never tried those; that's a good suggestion. More info would certainly be welcome (maybe in a new Q&A).

Answer (score 7):

To model $x=b \implies y=1$, where $L \le x \le U$, you can do the following:
\begin{align}
L y^- + b y + (b+\delta)y^+ \le x &\le (b-\delta) y^- + b y + U y^+\\
y^- + y + y^+ &= 1 \\
y^-, y, y^+ &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
In fact, this formulation also enforces the converse $y=1 \implies x=b$.

Comment: If we assume $L=b-\delta$ and $U=b+\delta$, then the first constraint is essentially: $L y^- + b y + Uy^+ \le x \le L y^- + b y + U y^+$ or $x = L y^- + b y + U y^+$.

Comment: True, but the idea here is that $\delta>0$ is small, so those assumptions on $L$ and $U$ would imply that $x$ is essentially constant.  The more useful setting would be when $L\ll b\ll U$.