# Binary variable to count appearances

Tags: modeling, logical-constraints, binary-variable

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an optimization variable. Now, at a constraint, I would like to count how many times a value, say $2$, appears in $x$ decision.

I think we can have a binary variable $y_i$ indicating whether $x_i =2$. So, $x_i - 2 = 0$ should imply $y_i = 1$. But, anything except $0$ should imply $y_i = 0$. What is the easiest way for this?

Note: since we can subtract $2$ from each element of $x$, we are interested in the number of zeros in $x-2$. So, 'the number of zeros in a decision vector' constraint will also make it.

We may assume $x$ consists of elements $x_i< M$ for some constant $M$

Comment: You can't really check for exact inequality. If you're willing to allow a small tolerance around 2 (say), then the approach described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/34/38) might work to set your $y_i$ variables.

Comment: I think there should be something with demeaning $x$ and then taking the absolute values... But, not sure.

Comment: What do you mean "demeaning" $x$?

Comment: $x_i - 2$ for all $i$. Now I tried to use Yalmip's iff command. Apparently, this works. But idk how

Comment: Just to clarify, what you want is to define a variable $y$ associated with an $x$ such that $y=1$ iff $x=2$ (otherwise $y=0$)?

Comment: True! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 8):

As LarrySnyder610 said, you cannot do exactly what you want when $x_i$ is continuous. (You can if it is an integer variable.) I discussed how to model this particular issue here: [Flagging a Specific Variable Value](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2015/02/flagging-specific-variable-value.html).