# How can I model this binary logic?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint, binary-variable

I am looking for a constraint to express the following:

IF W1 = 0 AND W2 = 0 THEN Y = 0 
IF W1 = 0 AND W2 = 1 THEN Y = 1 
 
IF W1 = 1 AND W2 = 0 THEN Y = 0 
IF W1 = 1 AND W2 = 1 THEN Y <= 1

Variables W1, W2, Y are binaries. 
Y is determined by the aforementioned relations.

Comment: With your previous question (which has been answered), you should be able to do this one easily. Otherwise you did not understand the previous one, obviously :) I suggest you give it a try and the community will guide you based on your try.

Comment: Well, I understand that the previous one is correct, but I am not good enough to get to the new one.

Comment: Do you understand @RobPratt's explanation ? If not, how do you relate both $Y$s in the two questions ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with what Rob was writting about.

Comment: Related: [How to model If A≤B then Y=1, otherwise Y=0](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3493/491)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in your other question, the fourth proposition is a tautology.  The other three propositions can be expressed as
$$
((\neg W_1 \land \neg W_2) \implies \neg Y)
\land
((\neg W_1 \land W_2) \implies Y)
\land
((W_1 \land \neg W_2) \implies \neg Y)
$$
More simply, combine your first and third propositions and omit the fourth one to obtain
$$
(\neg W_2 \implies \neg Y)
\land
((\neg W_1 \land W_2) \implies Y)
$$

Now rewrite in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), by replacing $P \implies Q$ with $\neg P \lor Q$, pushing $\neg$ inwards, and distributing $\lor$ over $\land$:
$$
(W_2 \lor \neg Y) \land ((W_1 \lor \neg W_2) \lor Y)\\
(W_2 + (1 - Y) \ge 1) \land (W_1 + (1 - W_2) + Y \ge 1)\\
(W_2 \ge Y) \land (W_1 + Y \ge W_2)
$$

Several other examples are [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22conjunctive%20normal%20form%22).

A good reference for this is:

Raman, R. and I.E. Grossmann, *Relation Between MILP Modelling and Logical Inference for Chemical Process Synthesis*, **Computers Chem. Engng.** 15 (1991).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Comment: Ok, I think I have got it. <br/>
W1 + W2 => Y <br/>
W1 - W2 => -Y <br/>
W1 - W2 <= 1  - Y <br/>

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of Rob's comprehensive answer, the problem is a bit strange. The last constraint is always met, and in the others  $W_1$ does not affect the result, almost. That's why I get the trivial solution $Y = W_2$. However, if $W_1 = W_2 = 1$, then $Y$ can take both 0 and 1.