# Write in ILP: If $x$ within range then $s=1$, else $0$

Tags: linear-programming, logical-constraints

How can write the following function in LP:

$$
s=
\begin{cases}
1 & 1 \leq x \leq C \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ where $x$ takes only non-negative integers and $C$ is some large constant integer.

I've tried using big M, and came up with conditions for $s=1$.
\begin{align}
x-M \cdot (1-s) &\leq C\\
x+M \cdot (1-s) &\geq 1 \\
\end{align}
But I wonder how to force $s=0$ when $x=0$ or $x\ge C+1$.

Comment: Do you want $s\in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ or $x \in B \Rightarrow s \in A$ 
 (where $A$ and $B$ are the set of values for variables $s$ and $x$)?

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2632/123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use three binary variables $r,s,t$ for the three intervals and impose linear constraints:
$$r+s+t = 1 \\
0r+1s+(C+1)t \le x \le 0r+Cs+Mt
$$
Then
\begin{align}
r = 1 &\implies x = 0 \\
s = 1 &\implies 1 \le x \le C \\
t = 1 &\implies C + 1 \le x \le M \\
\end{align}

If you prefer, treat $r$ as a slack variable and instead impose linear constraints:
$$s+t\le 1 \\
1s+(C+1)t \le x \le Cs+Mt
$$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to $s$, add a binary variable $u$ and the constraint $s + u \le 1$. The remaining constraints would be
\begin{align*}
x & \le1+M(s+u)\\
x & \ge s\\
x & \ge Cu\\
x & \le C+Mu.
\end{align*}
If $s=0=u$ this reduces to $x\le 1$. If $s=1$, $u=0$ and the constraints reduce to $1\le x\le C$. Finally, if $u=1$, $s=0$ and the constraints become $C\le x\le 1+M$.

As always, there are boundary issues, meaning that $s$ is ambiguous when $x=1$ and when $x=C$. The only way to remove the ambiguity requires that you make values of $x$ slightly less than 1 or slightly greater than $C$ infeasible.

Comment: Because $x$ is integer here, you can use $\epsilon = 1$ to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @RobPratt Good catch -- I saw the part about $x$ integer and promptly forgot it.