# MILP constraint modelling

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

Lets assume $x$, $y$ are non negative continuous variables and $P$ an integer variable assuming either the value $1$  or the value $2$.

How could I possibly model the relation

If $x = y$ then $P = 2$ else $P = 1$ ?

Comment: Note that $P-1$ is binary and apply https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2632/500 with your $x-y$ as $x$, $0$ as $b$, and $P-1$ as $y$.

Comment: Hugh, I will need to introduce another two binaries? That is frustrating. Thank you very much Rob.

Comment: Well, you can eliminate one of the additional binary variables by substitution if you want.  Also, if you instead wanted to enforce only $P=2 \implies x=y$, you wouldn't need any new variables.

Comment: No, this is not what I need to enforce. Anyway, how would the constraint then look like?

Comment: $(L_x - U_y)(2 - P) \le x -y \le (U_x - L_y)(2 - P)$, where $L$ and $U$ are lower and upper bounds on the variables.

Comment: I see it. Wow! Thanks again!

Comment: @RobPratt You should convert your comments to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $P−1$ is binary and apply the formulation in

[In an integer program, how I can force a binary variable to equal 1 if some condition holds?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond/2632#2632)

with your $x−y$ as $x$, $0$ as $b$, and $P−1$ as $y$.

If you instead wanted to enforce only $P=2 \implies x=y$, you wouldn't need any new variables.  Just let $L$ and $U$ be lower and upper bounds on the variables, and impose
$$(L_x−U_y)(2−P) \le x − y  \le (U_x−L_y)(2−P).$$