# Summation of Binary Variables Pushing a Binary Variable

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

I'm modeling a problem where I have a set of binary decision variables $x_{ij}$ that has a value of 1 if the person $i$ is allocated to day $j$ or 0 otherwise.

I have another set of binary decision variables $n_{jk}$ that has a value of 1 if the $j$'s day has $k$ persons assigned to it.

I need a way to force the $n_{jk}$ to 1 if the $\sum x_{ij} = k$, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! Have you looked at other related questions on the site, such as [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond)?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have, but I had to insert another binary variable in my model, it worked too. But the answer by @RobPratt worked as well without additional variables. Thank you again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_k n_{jk} &= 1 &&\text{for all $j$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_k k n_{jk} &= \sum_i x_{ij} &&\text{for all $j$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} selects one count for each day. Constraint \eqref{2} makes the selected count consistent with $x$ for each day.