# How to formulate an MIP so that a binary variable is 0 or 1 depending on whether another variable is nonzero?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a binary indicator variable $i \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ and an integer variable $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I am trying to come up with a formulation in which $i = 0$ if $c = 0$ and $i = 1$ if $c \neq 0$.
However, I am having trouble accomplishing this.
I tried formulating it as the minimum of two functions but that was not successful.
I tried creating two different copies of $i$ (one for if $c < 0$ and one for if $c > 0$). However that did not prove fruitful either.
I also tried formulating it using step functions combined with minimizing two functions.
However that also failed.
Is there a trick to deal with such programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $L \le c\le U$ for some constants $L$ and $U$.  Introduce binary variables $x$ and $y$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
L x + 0(1-i) + 1y \le c &\le -1 x + 0(1-i) + U y\\
x + (1-i) + y &= 1 \\
x, i, y &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
The three cases correspond to

- $(x,i,y)=(1,1,0)$ and $c\in[L,-1]$
- $(x,i,y)=(0,0,0)$ and $c = 0$
- $(x,i,y)=(0,1,1)$ and $c\in[1,U]$

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond/2632#2632

Comment: I don't think I follow this. According to this, it would seem that if $c \in [L, -1]$, then it must be that $x = 1$ and hence $i = 0$. However, we want $i = 1$ in that case. We want $i = 1$ whenever $c\neq 0$ (regardless of whether $c$ is positive or negative). Could you please clarify if I have made a mistake? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had the roles of $i$ and $1-i$ reversed.  Corrected now.