# Assistance in formulating implication constraints for inequalities

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following logical implications, where $\delta$ is a binary variable, $D_{j}$ and $A_{j}$ are nonnegative discrete variables, and $p_{j}$ are nonnegative discrete parameter values.

$$\delta = 1 \implies D_{j}+p_{j}\gt A_{j} \lor D_{j}+p_{j}\lt A_{j} \tag1\label1$$

$$D_{j}+p_{j}\gt A_{j} \lor D_{j}+p_{j}\lt A_{j} \implies \delta = 1 \tag2\label2$$

Comment: $\delta$ is a binary variable?

Comment: Yes, δ is a binary variable. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the formulation given in https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2632/500 with $y=1-\delta$, $x=D_j-A_j$, and $b=-p_j$.

Assuming by “discrete” you mean that $D_j$ and $A_j$ are integer-valued, you can use a tolerance of $1$ (the $\delta$ in the linked answer).

---

If you want to enforce only $(1)$, introduce binary variables $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, and impose linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\delta &\le \delta_1 + \delta_2 \\
-D_j - p_j + A_j + 1 &\le M_1 (1-\delta_1) \\
D_j + p_j - A_j + 1 &\le M_2 (1-\delta_2)
\end{align}

If you want to enforce only $(2)$,
consider its contrapositive
$$\delta = 0 \implies D_{j}+p_{j}\le A_{j} \land D_{j}+p_{j}\ge A_{j},$$
which you can enforce via
\begin{align}
D_j + p_j - A_j &\le M_3 \delta \\
-D_j - p_j + A_j &\le M_4 \delta
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. may I ask about enforcing each separately? It seems that your explanation in the link is bidirectional concurrently.

Comment: Thank you again, this helps a lot. Also, thank you for editing my question. It is much clearer after editing.