# Could you model this if -else statement

Tags: modeling, logical-constraints

I need to build a if-else constraint for this statement, where $c_j$ and $x_{ij}$ are decision variables, and $m_i$ is a constant:

if $c_j$ = $m_i$ then $x_{ij}$ = 1 else $x_{ij} = 0$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/2632/500